# Windows Service (413) Request Entity Too Large

Tags: c#, wcf, app-config

Please do not delete this as a duplicate
I have a windows service that I am passing an array of objects to.  When the array contains less than 150 objects it works successfully.  When I pass more than 150 objects I get the (413) Request Entity Too Large Error.
I have tried the feedback from other articles regarding readerQuotas node values and maxReceivedMessageSize, but I am still receiving the error and I am stuck as to what I am still doing wrong.
Here is the app.config of the windows service:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="basicHttpBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000000"
                  maxStringContentLength="2000000000"
                  maxArrayLength="2000000000" 
                  maxBytesPerRead="2000000000" 
                  maxNameTableCharCount="2000000000" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="wsHttpBindingNoSecurity" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
                    <message establishSecurityContext="false" negotiateServiceCredential="false"/>
                </security>
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000000"
                  maxStringContentLength="2000000000"
                  maxArrayLength="2000000000" 
                  maxBytesPerRead="2000000000" 
                  maxNameTableCharCount="2000000000" />
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
        <mexHttpBinding>
            <binding name="mexHttpBinding"/>
        </mexHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="Service1Behavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
        <service name="SE.Responder.Integration.AmiOutboundService.AmiObService" behaviorConfiguration="Service1Behavior">
            <endpoint address="wsHttp" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBindingNoSecurity" contract="SE.Responder.Integration.AmiOutboundService.IAmiObService">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost"/>
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="basicHttp" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding" name="basicHttp" contract="SE.Responder.Integration.AmiOutboundService.IAmiObService"/>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/SE.Responder.Integration.AmiOutboundService/AmiObService/"/>
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

And here is the app.config of the executable that passes the data to the windows service:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IAmiObService" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" >
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000000"
                  maxStringContentLength="2000000000"
                  maxArrayLength="2000000000" 
                  maxBytesPerRead="2000000000" 
                  maxNameTableCharCount="2000000000" />
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/SE.Responder.Integration.AmiOutboundService/AmiObService/AmiOBService" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IAmiObService" contract="AmiObService.IAmiObService" name="WSHttpBinding_IAmiObService" />
</client>
```

Comment: We will vote to close as a duplicate if it is a duplicate; we won't if it isn't.  Asking us not to doesn't change that.

Comment: Ok, I used a poor choice of words.  I was wanting to note that I have tried the things I have found in other similar issues without success so far.

Comment: If I may offer some advice as a long-time SO user: when I ask a question on SO and I've tried solutions from other questions that I suspect may be used as a duplicate, I cite those questions in my question along with a brief explanation what it said to do and how it doesn't resolve my issue.  Granted, that may help it get closed *sooner*, but in my experience if my question isn't actually a duplicate, it won't be closed and doing this helps us get to a solution sooner.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the source code for the application that was having this issue, I found that the wcf service was being hosted in the C# code.  I then applied the fix in code as described in the following stack overflow issue,
[MaxReceivedMessageSize in WCF Hosted Service in console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850690/maxreceivedmessagesize-in-wcf-hosted-service-in-console-application),
specifically the following lines,
var wsHttpBinding = new WSHttpBinding();
wsHttpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
                Service.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(TInterfaceContract), wsHttpBinding, EndpointAddress);

which corrected the issue.